# Large Cedar tree with brown needles

Tags: trees

Large Cedar tree next to grass fire.  It looked okay after the fire however 4 days later the needles have turned brown on the side nearest the grass fire.  What can I do to help it recover and/or will it ever recover?

Answer (score 2):

Realistically - wait and see. It took some damage, and there really isn't a lot you can do other than allow it to recover, if the damage wasn't too extensive.

Comment: And of course tell us after that, preferably with a picture now and a month from now :)